# SQLAlchemy Session add() return value

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

working on pyramid with sqlalchemy:

```
newjob_obj=Job(name=name,job_propery=job_property,sizeX=sizeX,
    sizeY=sizeY,quantity=quantity,timeline=timeline,
    description=description,remarks=remarks,
    client_id=client_id,created_by=created_by,status=status
)
new_job=session.add(newjob_obj)
print('Return newJob value %s\n' % new_job)
```

Here new_job is printing as `None`.
add function of session returns object or not.  Please help.

Answer (score 44):

To answer your question in the comment of @mark's answer - in order to receive your "inserted ID" after the commit:

```
session.add(newjob_obj)
session.commit()
```

You should refresh the inserted object with:

```
session.refresh(newjob_obj)
print newjob_obj.id
```

Hope it helps ..

Answer (score 9):

This is the expected output. `add()` does not return a value. [The documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add):

> Place an object in the Session.
>
> Its state will be persisted to the database on the next flush
>   operation.
>
> Repeated calls to add() will be ignored. The opposite of add() is
>   expunge().

[The code](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py#L1425):

```
def add(self, instance, _warn=True):
    """Place an object in the ``Session``.

    Its state will be persisted to the database on the next flush
    operation.

    Repeated calls to ``add()`` will be ignored. The opposite of ``add()``
    is ``expunge()``.

    """
    if _warn and self._warn_on_events:
        self._flush_warning("Session.add()")

    try:
        state = attributes.instance_state(instance)
    except exc.NO_STATE:
        raise exc.UnmappedInstanceError(instance)

    self._save_or_update_state(state)
```

The add method does not return a value. When a Python function does not return a value, the function acts as if it returns `None`. If you wanted to print out the job, you would instead print:

```
session.add(newjob_obj)
print('Return newJob value %s\n' % newjob_obj)
```

You see, SQLAlchemy will not really do anything important (like run a query against a database) when you `add()` an object to the session. What it will do is just keep track of the fact that the object exists. Then when you do a...

```
session.commit()
```

...all of the objects that you added are INSERTed into the database (among other things, like doing UPDATE and DELETE for modified and removed objects).

See the [using the session chapter](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html) in he documentation for more info.

Comment: Thanks Mark ..
session.add(newjob_obj)

n while i was doing the hands on as above,i am not able to get the newjob_obj.id after doing sesson.commit().
But i am able to get newjob_obj.id if i do session.flush().Please let me know how to commit using session.flush() or session.commit()

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For SQLite, once you commit, you can directly get the inserted id from the object:

```
session.add(newjob_obj)
session.commit()
print('Return newJob id %d\n' % newjob_obj.id)
```

Comment: Also true for Postgres. The relevant doc explaining this is [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/orm_data_manipulation.html#flushing).